# Javascript: Unable to disable refresh action when mouse pointer focus on URL address bar

Tags: javascript

I am having a Javascript function that prevent my user from refreshing the page via either `CTRL+R` or `F5`. It works perfectly fine but here comes the problem, which I have found that I am still able to refresh the page when I focus my mouse pointer on the URL address bar. How is this possible?

Here is the code that I have written to prevent page refresh:

```
function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 || (e.which || e.keyCode) == 82) e.preventDefault(); };
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on("keydown", disableF5);
});
```

Comment: *"How is this possible?"* - Do you mean how is it that refreshing via the address bar is possible? Or are you trying to ask how to prevent that? Note that there's a third way to refresh the page: right-click and then choose "Refresh" (or equivalent) from the context menu. Bottom line is you really can't stop the user refreshing the page - why would you want to?

Comment: @nnnnnn, I mean how is it that refreshing via the address bar still possible after adding the js function to it. "why would you want to?" - For some reason that I have to disable the page refresh although I know it is discouraged.

Comment: It's still possible because your *key* event handler only handles *key* events *on the document*. The address bar is not part of the document. In any case a determined user could use the browser's dev tools to disable your JS, or if all else failed they could just close the page and re-open it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to prevent the user from using their browser. It's not friendly and any hack you find to work in some situations will not work in all (except if your intention is to annoy them, then it will work for that purpose).

Comment: Hi. I know this method is discouraged. While I am trying to search for another solution for my page, I have to use this method.

Comment: @BrianCheong why are you doing this at all? what are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That would cause a lot of usability and security concerns. The closest you can go to it is your code, which is bad enough in itself. Why on earth might you want to do this? It is starting to sound you might want to use a native app instead.